# retrofit2 connection is throwing errors when installed as apk

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm connecting to restful api with retrofit2.

When I try the code in the emulator console, it runs fine and connect to my web api.

But When I convert that to apk release mode and install it on my cell phone, then the code doesn't work.

Do you know if this is an normal behavior and when I upload to google playstore it will work fine?

```
    public void login(String email, String password)
    {
        //search at web api
        final User[] user = {new User()};
        APIInterface apiInterface;
        apiInterface = APIClient.getClient("http://url.com").create(APIInterface.class);
        Call<User> call1 = apiInterface.UserLogin(email, password);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<User>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().Id > 0)
                    {
                        user[0].Id = response.body().Id;
                        user[0].email = email;
                        user[0].tokenuser = response.body().tokenuser;
                        user[0].tokensession = response.body().tokensession;

                        //correct credentials
                        SaveOnPreferences(email, password);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this, Dashboard.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //wrong password
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.IncorrectCredentials, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "public void onFailure: " + user[0].Id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
```

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

class APIClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static Retrofit getClient(String url) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        //interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface APIInterface {

    @POST("/miracle/user/login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<User> UserLogin(@Field("email") String Email, @Field("password") String Password);

}
```

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User
{
    @SerializedName("Id")
    public int Id;

    @SerializedName("Fullname")
    public String fullname;

    @SerializedName("Email")
    public String email;

    @SerializedName("Password")
    public String password;

    @SerializedName("ValidEmail")
    public boolean validemail;

    @SerializedName("EnableNotification")
    public boolean enablenotification;

    @SerializedName("TokenUser")
    public String tokenuser;

    @SerializedName("TokenSession")
    public String tokensession;

    public  User(){

    }
...
}
```

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.zzz"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

The cellphone where I'm installing the apk is Huawei P30.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? What is happening on the phone when you try to launch it?

Comment: could you please share the error message or logs, also part of the implementation

Comment: Perhaps you can place the code into the post and note the error message you are receiving

Comment: Sammy, the public void onFailure method is executed. Thxs.

Comment: Maybe is a version feature constraint, what is your minimum api version in your build.gradle file and what is your smartphone version?

Comment: peterzinho16, I added that info above. Thxs.

Comment: something is wrong with your progurd in release build just disable the proguard and check if it work. this will confirm if your models or something are getting truncated or something and hence you are not able to map the data. it's not something related to retrofit i believe.

Comment: also enable the logging using the interceptors to check the logs getting generated

Answer (score 0):

I have the response:

I was trying to request a web api with http protocol (not ssl). Android does prevent it because it is an insecure way to transmit data.

The solution was found here: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)